# Roll-up multiple rows into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following result when I query multiple tabels/views and put the result in #Temp (I use MS SQL SERVER 2014)

The problem is that I cannot get all the relevant data on 1 row per organisation. For every "extra" value I get a new row so you get multiple rows which gives an undisered result.

```
Rows  |OrgNumb|OrgNam   |ProdNam| ValDec |AttrC   | AttrV    |
1     | 115   | Org1    | Acc   |  1.00  | Number | 09133444 |
2     | 115   | Org1    | Acc   |  1.00  | SBI    | 1089     |
3     | 115   | Org1    | Fac   |  1.00  | Number | 09133444 |
4     | 115   | Org1    | Fac   |  1.00  | SBI    | 1089     |
5     | 115   | Org1    | Rel   |  1.00  | Number | 09133444 |
6     | 115   | Org1    | Rel   |  1.00  | SBI    | 1089     |
7     | 119   | Org2    | Ord   |  1.00  | Number | 05558794 |
8     | 119   | Org2    | Ord   |  1.00  | SBI    | 1089     |
```

I need to have this result:

```
Rows |OrgNum |OrgNam|ProdN1|ValDec1|ProdN2|ValDec2|ProdN3|ValDec3|AttrC1 |AttrV1    |AttrC2 |AttrV2|
1    | 115   | Org1 | Acc  | 1.00  | Fac  | 1.00  | Rel  | 1.00  |Number | 09133444 | SBI   | 1089 |
2    | 119   | Org1 | Ord  | 1.00  |      |       |      |       |Number | 05558794 | SBI   | 1089 |
```

There are many more Columns but these are atm the essential ones and unlike this example not every Attribute (AttrC1) has a value.

I made something that had a simular purpose but the sourcedata is much simpler (code below). So the very first thing I did is to base it in the query below but it returns the wrong data. I then tried it with Pivot, stuff/XML PATH but none of them gave me the correct result. I looked @ countles examples but none of them could help me out.

```
SELECT   Period, Debitor,
         MAX( CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Product ELSE NULL END ) AS Product1,
         SUM( CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Amount  ELSE NULL END ) AS Amount1,
         MAX( CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Product ELSE NULL END ) AS Product2,
---- and so on
      SUM( CASE WHEN RN = 14 THEN Amount ELSE NULL END ) AS Amount14,
         SUM( price * Amount ) AS [Net price]
FROM     (
            SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Debitor, Debitor ORDER BY Period ) AS RN, *
            FROM     #TempVF
         ) AS RI
GROUP BY Period, Debitor
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0):

The following might help you:

```
DECLARE @cols AS VARCHAR(MAX), @query AS VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((select distinct ', 
            MAX(CASE WHEN ProdNam=''' + CAST(ProdNam as varchar(100)) + ''' THEN ProdNam ELSE '''' END) AS [ProdN' + CAST(sno as varchar(10)) +']
            ,MAX(CASE WHEN ValDec=''' + CAST(ValDec as varchar(100)) + ''' THEN ValDec ELSE '''' END) AS [ValDec' + CAST(sno as varchar(10)) +']
            ,MAX(CASE WHEN AttrC=''' + CAST(AttrC as varchar(100)) + ''' THEN AttrC ELSE '''' END) AS [AttrC' + CAST(sno as varchar(10)) +']
            ,MAX(CASE WHEN AttrV=''' + CAST(AttrV as varchar(100)) + ''' THEN AttrV ELSE '''' END) AS [AttrV' + CAST(sno as varchar(10)) +']'
                        /*---------------------------------you can add other columns similar to the above here----------------------------------*/
            FROM #t 
            FOR XML PATH(''),type).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,2,'')

exec ('SELECT 1 '' '', OrgNumb, OrgNam, ' + @Cols +'  FROM #t group by  OrgNumb, OrgNam')
```

Please find the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3208bc5b30976a578622b50e40c474b5)**.

Comment: Thanks it nicely rolls up the rows but I still have the problem that is shows multiple values. I am fiddling with it but so far no luck solving that problem.